# Why does water leak from the Cup?

Tags: rendering

When i use effector fluid settings on the cup, this happens

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HO-uIQhzunj32LCMI4JsTvL9A_yIWnR4/view?usp=sharing "Click Me!")

Comment: Please try to convert animation into anim gif and append to your post. If it will be bigger than 2MB, attach screens of the issue. External links are temporary and not accepted as main source of informations here. Thank you

Comment: And also, please take some time to describe what you tried to solve this :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specificly to Effector that is moving fast you can increase **Sampling Substeps**.

[image]

You would have to increase Domain Resolution Division anyway

- first because in this res the liquid would not pass the thin part of funnel and bottle neck
- it improves collision with effector
- also try increase **Timesteps** (how many steps between frame)

[image]

Scale down domain only into a dimension of expected fluid appearance.
Dont forget - domain resolution is represented by small cube in domain corner and value of resolution is calculated from longest edge.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the walls are to thin. Increase the wall thickness, the physics interpolation resolution or decrease the animation speed.